# pip install enable fails

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, chaco

Currently trying to install Chaco with the use of pip in my 2.7.3 environment.  When I run pip install chaco it fails with this error:

> error: Command "llvm-gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -I/Developer/Headers/FlatCarbon -I/Users/streetmapp/pythonDev/edx/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c build/src.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/kiva/quartz/ATSFont.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/build/src.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/kiva/quartz/ATSFont.o" failed with exit status 1

Going through the regular output, I came about this:

> C compiler: llvm-gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3
>
> compile options: '-I/Developer/Headers/FlatCarbon -      I/Users/streetmapp/pythonDev/edx/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c'
>
> llvm-gcc-4.2: build/src.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/kiva/quartz/ATSFont.c
>
> build/src.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/kiva/quartz/ATSFont.c:252:21: error: ATSFont.h: No such file or directory

I noticed that this is failing in regards to the enable package, which is a prereq of Chaco, and running pip install enable puts out the same.

Currently running on OS X Mountain Lion with python 2.7.3 within a virtualenv.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might have to install numpy first. chaco depends on numpy.

Comment: I have installed the following packages already with success:

NumPy

SciPy

IPython

matplotlib

Traits

Comment: The architecture flag doesnt seem to be right. It says i386 and 64 bit. Are you sure your mac is 64 bit supportable because i386 is not 64bit . ```-arch i386 -arch x86_64``` Try to use only one -arch flag.

Answer (score 4):

The Enable build is failing because it's looking for Carbon libraries that are no longer present in recent versions of the OS X SDK. While this has been addressed, it hasn't yet made it into a released (or tagged version) of the package.

In the meantime the only way to get Enable working on your system will be to clone the git repository https://github.com/enthought/enable.git and run setup.py yourself.

Comment: The Carbon-free version of Enable has now been released to the world. It should work correctly through pip on recent versions of OS X now.

Answer (score 2):

you can also do

```
pip install -e git+https://github.com/enthought/enable.git@fd2e69f24dbe07eedfc8f8fbde240c15ae495677#egg=enable-dev
```

which will install and compile enthought-dev

and you can later remove it with

```
pip remove enthought-dev
```